# How to update data using onclick even CHECKBOX without button submit in php and mysql

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

How, can i update status when i click the check box?..this's my code... i already find and try hard but realy i cant finding anything, please to take out me from this problem,, this's my some script...thank you

```
 if(isset($_POST["btnBaca"])) {

    // Query Update status
    $Kode       = isset($_GET['Kode']) ?  $_GET['Kode'] : $_POST['txtKode'];
    $mySql1 = "UPDATE pemesanan set status='DiBaca'  WHERE kd_pesan='$Kode'";
    $myQry1 = mysql_query($mySql1, $koneksidb) or die ("Gagal query".mysql_error());
    if($myQry1){

        echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0; url=?page=Pemesanan-Data'>";
    }
  exit;
}

elseif(!empty($_POST['btnKirim'])){

    $Kode       = isset($_GET['Kode']) ?  $_GET['Kode'] : $_POST['txtKode'];
    $mySql1 = "UPDATE pemesanan set status='DiKirim' WHERE kd_pesan='$Kode'";
    $myQry1 = mysql_query($mySql1, $koneksidb) or die ("Gagal query".mysql_error());
    if($myQry1){

        echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0; url=?page=Pemesanan-Data'>";
    }
     exit;
}
elseif(!empty($_POST['btnPending'])){

    $Kode       = isset($_GET['Kode']) ?  $_GET['Kode'] : $_POST['txtKode'];
    $mySql1 = "UPDATE pemesanan set status='Pending' WHERE kd_pesan='$Kode'";
    $myQry1 = mysql_query($mySql1, $koneksidb) or die ("Gagal query".mysql_error());
    if($myQry1){

        echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0; url=?page=Pemesanan-Data'>";
    }
     exit;
}
```

=========

```
<td align="center">
    <input class="button blue small" name="btnBaca" type="checkbox" value="R" >
    <input class="button red small" name="btnKirim" type="checkbox" value="D" />
    <input class="button orange small" name="btnPending" type="checkbox" value="P" />
    <?php echo $myData['status']; ?>
</td>
```

Comment: Can you be more precise and tell what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: the first i'am new in php and mysql and other languange..

how when I click the checkbox status option automatically performs the update status without pressing the submit button

Comment: Rey, show your html code of checkbox page and please tell what you are trying to achive

Comment: hello...antony my html code of checkbox in my tag you can see the input type checkbox

Answer (score 0):

This is kinda simple :)

```html
<?php
function update2() {
$conn = new mysqli('host', 'name', 'pass', 'database');
if ($conn->query("UPDATE `table` SET `value1`='1', `value2`='2'") === TRUE) {
echo 'YES!';
}
?>
```

```html
<button onclick="update()">Click me</button>
<p id="update">
<script language="javascript>
function update() {
    document.getElementById("update").innerHTML = "<?php update2(); ?>";
</script>
```

Comment: oke thank u..i will try, but how if i using checkbox not button type?

Answer (score 0):

You can try by this way

```
<p id="costumersdata">Print Sucess or Fail</p>

<input class="button blue small" name="btnBaca" type="checkbox" value="R" onClick="gotoupdate(this.value)">
<input class="button red small" name="btnKirim" type="checkbox" value="D" onClick="gotoupdate(this.value)"/>
<input class="button orange small" name="btnPending" type="checkbox" value="P" onClick="gotoupdate(this.value)"/>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function gotoupdate(btnBaca){
    $.post("ajax.php?btnBaca="+btnBaca, 
        function(data){
            $("#costumersdata").html(data);
    }); 
}
</script>
```

On your ajax.php page

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["btnBaca"])) {

    // Query Update status
    $Kode       = $_POST["btnBaca"];

    if($Kode == 'R'){
        $mySql1 = "UPDATE pemesanan set status='DiBaca'  WHERE kd_pesan='$Kode'";
    }else if($Kode == 'D'){
        $mySql1 = "UPDATE pemesanan set status='DiKirim' WHERE kd_pesan='$Kode'";
    }else{
        $mySql1 = "UPDATE pemesanan set status='Pending' WHERE kd_pesan='$Kode'";
    }

    $myQry1 = mysql_query($mySql1, $koneksidb) or die ("Gagal query".mysql_error());

    if($myQry1){

        echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0; url=?page=Pemesanan-Data'>";
    }
  exit;
}
?>
```

Comment: hello shaymol sorry to late reply ur message..i have tried but nothing