# How do I determine if my ajax request is failing on the client side or server side?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I'm trying to click a picture and change a database value to "0" via an onclick Javascript function. I looked at a few examples but I can't seem to make it work.

[How can you use php in a javascript function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8471945/how-can-you-use-php-in-a-javascript-function)

[How to update data using onclick even CHECKBOX without button submit in php and mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33185396/how-to-update-data-using-onclick-even-checkbox-without-button-submit-in-php-and)

[Update Database from Javascript onClick By Ajax PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36691081/update-database-from-javascript-onclick-by-ajax-php)

This is the index.html file

```
<script language="javascript">
    function update() {
        $.post("update.php", { num: 0 }, function(result) { 
           alert(result); 
        });
    }
</script>

<img src="image.png" onclick="update()">
```

This is the update.php file.

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "dbname";


$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$num = $_POST["num"];
$id = 1;
$sql2 = "UPDATE db SET Column1='$num' WHERE id='$id'";

if ($conn->query($sql2) === TRUE) {
    echo "Updated";
} else {
    echo "Failed";
}
```

Would someone please point out what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Please, [quit using `alert()` for troubleshooting.](http://stravid.com/en/stop-the-javascript-alert-madness/), use `console.log()` instead.

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)***. Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

Comment: [Have you watched the AJAX request / response in the browser's developer tools? Have you included the jQuery library in the project? Are there any errors reported? Are you running this on a web-server?](http://jayblanchard.net/basics_of_jquery_ajax.html)

Comment: What is the server response ? the `result` value ?

Comment: Break this down. Is your problem in Javascript (F12 console) or is it in PHP and updating the database (Php error log)

Comment: Did you check ajax response in your browser console?

Comment: Thank you all. Jay solved it.

Answer (score 0):

Hoping that your table name is not named  `db` You should use a table name  (not db)  and if the values for column1 and id are number you don't need  quotes

```
 $sql2 = "UPDATE your_table_name SET Column1=$num WHERE id=$id";
```